# Why does MonoTouch debugger disconnects after some time?

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, monodevelop, soft-debugger

When I debug an app on my iPad, it's often the case that when I get back to it after some time has passed, the debugging session has already stopped but the app is still running.

It's very frustrating because I specifically baked some `UIWebView` debugging tools into the app like reloading external content on a swipe so I don't have to recompile it every time I change something.

I've looked at the settings and found nothing like “debugging timeout”.
  What's the matter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out, the problem was in Auto Lock.
It unloads the application, and thus soft debugger's connection is lost.

Setting Auto Lock to 15 minutes solved my problem.